# Not sure how to work with a function which has the same finite domain and codomain.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Here's the problem set:

> Let A = {1,2,3,4,5,6}. In each of the following, give an example of a function f : A → A with the indicated properties, or explain why no such function exists.
>
> (a) f is bijective, but is not the identity function f(x) = x.
>
> (b) f is neither one-to-one nor onto.
>
> (c) f is one-to-one, but not onto.
>
> (d) f is onto, but not one-to-one.

I'm having trouble with this one because having a finite domain and codomain seem very "rigid" to me in the sense that `f : A → A` where A is finite is inherently bijective, so I'm not sure how to deviate from that. Here's where I'm at so far:

a) Doesn't exist because for f to stay bijective, it *has* to be the identity function.

b) Doesn't exist because I can't write `f(x) = 10` because 10 isn't part of A.

c) Doesn't exist because `f : A → A` is inherently bijective.

d) Doesn't exist because `f : A → A` is inherently bijective.

Comment: All allowed functions are permutations.  What applies?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I'm very new to discrete, so I'm not sure what a permutation is in this context. I wish I knew how to respond.

Comment: If you have an erasable board of some sort, write the numbers $1$ through $10$ at the top. Some distance below write the numbers $1$ through $10$ again. Think of the top row as the domain and the bottom row as the codomain. For each part of the problem see if you can draw arrows from the top row to the bottom row that will satisfy that part of the problem.

Comment: Visualizing it helps, thanks.

Comment: Permutation means rearrangement.

Comment: (a) is quite simple: $f(1)=6, f(2)=5$, etc

Comment: Other cases are also very simple, considering the definitions.

Comment: The function $f: A \to A$ defined by $f(x) = 1$ for each $x \in A$ is a valid function, so not every function $f: A \to A$ is a bijection.  We merely require that each element in $A$ has an image that is also in $A$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.